# PHP: RegEx to detect normal human readable string?

Tags: php, regex, string

say I have few String's like:

```
[0]Hey how are you?
[1]13A315Bdas
[2]d3s315
[3]Billy
[4]daa2315Fasd
```

How can I use regex in PHP to roll out number 1, 2 and 4 as invalid strings and keep 0 and 3 as valid strings?

So something like:

```
LettersNumbersLetters = false;
NumbersLetters = false;
Numbers = true;
Letters = true;
```

So either just Numbers in String is valid, or just letters in String is valid.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 no, I am useless at RegEx and this is kinda urgent so I can't take time and read and practice. My project is due tomorrow.

Comment: But `?` this neither a number nor a letter.

Comment: @AvinashRaj "?" can be ignored altogether.

Comment: What about `I'm fine.` or `Ahh!` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj wel okay I guess I forgot to mention that - characters can be ignored altogether.

Comment: it's better to use a parser instead.

Comment: Why not use logical operators and [Character type checking](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) ?

Comment: you'll have better luck researching RegEx for 20 minutes than you will asking the SO community to do your work for you without any effort on your own behalf.

Comment: Also, regex alone isn't going to succeed. Regex could find *word-like* clusters of characters, but it isn't going to differentiate between "hello" and "hsdjkhe" -- both satisfy the same requirements, but one has meaning to us as English speakers and the other does not. Regex doesn't have a dictionary of English words to reference. So, you'll have to examine the strings using several pre-qualifications (not numbers, not a bunch of symbols), *then* you'll have to compare the strings against a dictionary to see if it is meaningful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?<=^\[)[035-9](?=\])` regex and if a string contains a match, it is valid. See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eA8lZ9/1).